# MKMapkit - How to find a point at x meters from the start of a MKPolyline

Tags: ios, mapkit, coordinates, mkpolyline

i 've got a MKPolyline, and i want to find the coordinate of the point on this line which is at 5 meters from the start of the line.

How can i handle that ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: `5mts` to which direction. You have to find direction also to calculate coordinates.

Comment: If you are able to find the angle(direction) between them, you can find coordinates using `Haversine` Formula depicted here http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: Ok, my line is between 2 points so i have the direction if it's necessary !

Comment: See above comment if you are able to get directions

Comment: Ok, thank you i've seen the paragraph Destination point given distance and bearing from start point ! It 's exactly what I want !